# How can I change the page's resources URL?

Tags: html, web, resources, meta

I know that there's a meta tag to change the page's resources' incompleted URLs.
For example:
If I were to load a JS file using a `<script>` tag to get the file **main.js**, then the page would auto-complete the src from "./main.js" to "https://example.com/main.js"

```
<!-- This file is hosted on https://example.com -->
<script src="./main.js"></script><!-- will load https://example.com/main.js -->
```

But when you add the meta tag that I've talked about previously and set it to auto-complete with "https://example2.com" and tried to load the same JS file in "https://example.com" the website would load the file from "https://example2.com"

```
<!-- This file is hosted on https://example.com -->
<meta name="..." url="https://example2.com">
<script src="./main.js"></script><!-- will load https://example2.com/main.js -->
```

What's the name of that meta tag? And, if what I said wasn't true, is there any other way to achieve the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a `meta` tag like this exists. It's less that the browser 'auto-completes' links, but more that it converts relative links to absolute ones to display them in the console.

Usually, accessing scripts from another domain is quite rare, by which I mean it only occurs once or twice on a page. For only a few instances, I would just use the full URL `https://example2.com` in my `src` attributes.

If you needed the domain to remain variable, or have very many instances of it, you could use PHP. At the top of your page, specify a variable `$sourceURL`:

```html
<?php $sourceURL = 'https://example2.com' ?>
```

And then reference this variable in your `src` attributes, eg. :

```html
<script src="<?php echo($sourceURL) ?>/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: This won't work, as I'm not hosting this code on a server with PHP support.